regex to convert an YAML object into string in sed
I have an yaml object like below
input="poc_string: 'This is my succeeding string!'
poc_fail: false"

I want to convert this to the string below
'{"poc_string":"This is my succeeding string!","poc_fail":false}'

The following has to change

single qoutes aroung This is my succeeding string! to double quotes
all strings before and after : except true or false should get enclosed in double quotes " "
the new line should be replaced with a comma ,. However, if the new line is the very end, , should not be inserted.

This needs to be done in sed
I am new to sed and bash in general so, I have started with the below command (going one by one)
output=$(echo $sql | sed -r "s/'/\"/g" | sed -r "s/: /:/g"| sed -rE "s/\(\w*\):/\"&\"/g")
echo $output


First, I replaced ' with ", worked fine
Second, replaced spaces after :, worked fine
Now, trying to wrap all text before : with quotes and it doesn't work.

my output as of now is poc_string:'This is my succeeding string!' poc_fail:false
How to get the output I desire?
ps: I am working with ubuntu 22.04.3 (it was mentioned in some online artifacts the OS is important)

Why in sed? Really not ideal. So much could go wrong.

I can't have python installation (some internal restrictions) and since I am new to bash, sed is the only solution I can think of.

obviously yq would be ideal... If it's a one-time thing, use an online YAML to JSON converter. Can you use java? Maybe Perl?

Thanks. What you say makes sense. I will try & see if I can get the restrictions "waived" and will definitely use one of the other solutions (they are mush easier & I don't have to worry down the line if there is change in some part of the text)

Instead of using sed, you might want to consider using something that has a real YAML parser, for example yq.
Or you could use Python:
python3 -c 'import json, yaml, sys; json.dump(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)'


This might work for you (GNU sed):
 sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x
         s/^(.*): '\''?([^'\'']*)'\''?$/"\1":"\2"/mg
         s/"(true|false)"/\1/mg
         y/\n/,/' file

Slurp the file into memory.
Use pattern matching to surround keys and values by double quotes and remove a space.
Return true and false values as were.
Replace newlines by ,'s

Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it did not work for me. The input is a variable & may be I am not saving it in the file properly, I am not sure. However, thanks to you guidance I was able to get what I want with this code output=$(echo $input | sed -r "s/'/\"/g" | sed -r "s/: /:/g" | sed -E "s/(\w+):/\"\1\":/g" | sed -E "s/\"(\s+)\"/\",\"/g" | sed -E "s/(.*)/'{&}'/") Didn't have to touch the 'true/false' text as of now.

output=$(echo $input | sed -r "s/'/\"/g" | sed -r "s/: /:/g" | sed -E "s/(\w+):/\"\1\":/g" | sed -E "s/:(\w+)/:\"\1\"/g"  | sed -E "s/\"(\s+)\"/\",\"/g" | sed -E "s/\"(true|false)\"/\1/g" | sed -E "s/(.*)/'{&}'/") this would take care of "true/false" as well

@moys : Note that potong has only used sed once and has chained together all the substitutions as an "in-line" sed script. There are cases where using multiple seds can't be avoided but the general case is to put all operations into one call to sed. (yes, in a modern system, it doesn't matter too much about efficiency, but if you rely on multi-seds going forward, and you're processing large amounts of data, such constructs can make a difference in efficiencies.) Glad you solved your problem. Good luck!

@shellter Totally agree with you. I am a newbie to sed, so going step by step so that I can understand what is going on. Will try to improve on this.

sed is great for doing s/old/new on individual lines but for anything else just use awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, etc. using any awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input="poc_string: 'This is my succeeding string!'
poc_fail: false"

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=" *: *"; printf "\047{" }
    {
        tag = $1
        sub(/[^:]+: */,"")
        gsub(/\047/,"\"")
        printf "%s\"%s\":%s", sep, tag, $0
        sep = ","
    }
    END { print "}\047" }
' <<< "$input"


$ ./tst.sh
'{"poc_string":"This is my succeeding string!","poc_fail":false}'


given how 'messy' the manipulation of the input is, sed is less than ideal, an awk 'solution' seemed the way to go - as others have alluded to.
below, an awk (GNU Awk 5.0.1) offering, tested on linux mint OS 20.x .
cat moys.awk 
BEGIN{ FS="[=:!]"; RS="" } 
{
    gsub(/: /,":",$0); gsub(/'/,"\"",$0);
    sub(/"/,"", $5); sub(/\n/,"",$4);
    print "'{" $2 "\":" $3 "!\"," $4 "\":" $5 "}'"
}

cat input.yml 
input="poc_string: 'This is my succeeding string!'
poc_fail: false"

awk -f moys.awk input.yml 
'{"poc_string":"This is my succeeding string!","poc_fail":false}'

PS: @ed Morton - I couldn't directly comment on your solution, it needs an additional double quote at the end of the variable input declaration to replicate the users input .., if not appropriate to comment here, apologies.

I don't see a double quote missing from the end of my input, can you take another look as I think  you just missed it?

Your script wouldn't work for other input, e.g. "poc_string: 'This: where a=3 is my succeeding string'", as it's assuming some characters will/won't be present in the input strings.

wrt to the double quote, response is based on the premise that this a yaml object (and therefore in some yaml file, not a shell variable, and as such the double quotes are part of the object.

wrt to the assertion that it wouldn't work if the input is different, agreed, but I only worked on what was supplied, if the author posts something else ... all bets are off and the corresponding 'solution' would (hopefully) change to fit the challenged posed. (fingers X'd)

The only thing we can know for sure is that the input will not always be exactly the characters present in the example. After that we must make some guesses/assumptions about what the general case may be, e.g. the tag is before the first : on each line and doesn't contain :, and the value is either a '-enclosed string or the text true or false. Assuming anything beyond that (e.g. that the strings can't contain : or must always contain ! or that all white space will always be a single blank char) is pretty well guaranteeing that the resulting code won't work on real data.
